Interruptible disk usage tallies for users?
I want to obtain, for every one of my system's users (or at least, every one with a home directory under /home), the amount of disk space their files use. I have root access, but - there are many users with lots and lots of files, and the directory is an nfs-mount. So, counting is kind of slow; and my machine may be rebooted in the process, so I need to be able to resume counting after the machine is up again.
What would be a decent way of achieving this?
I don't very much mind the output format.
Notes:

I can't set quotas. I mean, I have root access, but I don't get to do what I want.


How long does a du -sm /home/* take?

For every share mounted over the network, try calculating the sub-totals for it at the system that is providing the share if at all possible. Tallying up disk usage per-user is likely to be much faster locally than over the network.

Which file system does /home use? You might find it more effective to use quotas for this, even if you don’t enforce limits.

@tink: It takes lots and lots of time.

@StephenKitt: See edit.

@telcoM: It's all a single NFS-mount.

@einpoklum enabling quotas doesn’t mean setting them — at its most basic, it enables tracking of disk usage per user (and optionally, per group and per “project”), without enforcing any limits.

@StephenKitt: I think that sounds like an answer.

@einpoklum it does, but I’m only familiar with Ext4 and XFS quotas on Linux; I’m not sure of the level of support for NFS quotas on Linux (I know NFS supports quotas because I used them on Solaris, but I get the impression the Linux situation isn’t great there).

do user machines (other than the one you're using) directly connect to the same NFS share? I ask because you say "I am root", which would indicate no_root_squash, and that would be a BIG Problem.

@MarcusMüller: root's home directory is not under /home, and is not nfs-mounted.

that has nothing to do with the problem you have! no_root_squash means that users can write their own suid binaries (something that otherwise only root can do), and I'm not sure which kind of access control you have, but allowing an NFS client to tell the NFS server that they are, in fact, requesting files on behalf of root, would basically allow any machine that users control to access all files, no matter who they belong to.

@MarcusMüller: Point taken, although this is not much of a problem in my case, for reasons.

@einpoklum as long as that reason is not "I chose to ignore it until I come up with a better solution", that's fine :) Just be advised that "plugging in your laptop, taking the IP address of the desktop PC you just unplugged, mounting the same NFS shares, and being root on your own laptop, reading everyone's files" is an "attack" that's been known around high school students for a couple of decades now.

@MarcusMüller: Yes, I realize that. I'm just not sharing more details because they're not relevant to the question.
